# How can I write Xelement values?

Tags: c#, xml, generics

I would like to create a method which collect custom childnode values from an xml file and rewrite whit datas from a form. I had an idea thet I collect the datas in an ArrayList and give it to the method. But I cant change it in a foreach, because it throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException( although the ArraList contains 8 elements and the incremental variable's value also 8). So I would ask for help.

Here is the Code:

```
  public static void Search(ArrayList nodeIds, ArrayList values)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Options.xml");
            int i = 0;
            foreach (XElement option in doc.Descendants("BasicOptions"))
            {
                foreach(string nodeId in nodeIds)
                {
                    if (option.Attribute("id").Value == nodeId)
                    {
                        foreach (XElement prop in option.Nodes())
                        {
                            prop.Value = values[i].ToString();
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.Save("Options.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure **i** isn't out of range? with i == 8 and values.Count == 8 it'll crash...

Comment: ArrayList??? What's that?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer don't you think it's touching to see ArrayList and LINQ to XML together?

Comment: @Adriano No, it's just a nightmare. ArrayList never existed!!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer :) I have to admit I felt touched, they reminds me 1.1 (even if they're what I first replaced). Actually even System.Xml.Linq classes used as "plain" System.Xml looks strange...

Comment: @Adriano Yeah. In fact, ArrayList became obsolete since .net 2.0 came out with generics. Execpting very very very legacy code, ArrayLists don't exist anymore! OP needs to go through the recycling machine :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `i` will go out of range without question because it is declared externally to **3** `foreach` statements and used within the center `foreach`.  You should rethink your approach.

I suggest, but without knowing your incoming values or why your calling this, to redclare your internal `foreach` as a `for` statement like the following:

```
public static void Search(ArrayList nodeIds, ArrayList values)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Options.xml");
    foreach (XElement option in doc.Descendants("BasicOptions"))
    {
        foreach (string nodeId in nodeIds)
        {
            if (option.Attribute("id").Value == nodeId)
            {
                var nodes = option.Nodes().ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count && i < values.Count; i++)
                {
                    XElement node = (XElement)nodes[i];
                    node.Value = values[i].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Save("Options.xml");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, you saved my day :) Thats almost the only way what I didn't try. But is works perfectly now. I'll vote you up as soon as I can.